# How to Make username field case insensitive in Dnago? Is my Implementation right?

Tags: python, django

I am in starting of my web project using Django and Django Rest Framework. I wanted my username field to be case Insensitive and hence I searched web about how to achieve it and got to this beautiful blog: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/06/how-to-implement-case-insensitive-username.html. He suggested this method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
        return self.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

for models.py

But when I wrote tests, they were failing because User.objects.get_by_natural_key was returning two user objects when I created two users with same username, but different case (ex: 'aniket' and 'Aniket').

So, I got through this approach :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager, AbstractUser
# Create your models here.


class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return super().create_user(username.lower(),email,password,**extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return super().create_superuser(username.lower(),email,password,**extra_fields)

    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(self.model.USERNAME_FIELD)
        return self.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})

class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

So, is this approach up to the mark?

Comment: If it works out for you then it should be fine.

Comment: This sounds fine, but maybe it might be a better idea to simply convert user's usernames to lowercase on registration and login? That way you know all usernames are lowercase in your database, and you just need to change two views that you will be writing anyway.

Comment: @JanMorawiec I thought about it, but I am going to make a rest API and hence user  may send anycase usernames. That is the reason , I wanted to work from core.